# Making Second Logo Disappear When Scrolling back up

Tags: jquery

I have 2 logos, one big, one small. When I scroll down the page, the smaller logo loads and the larger (original dissapears). What's really neat is that when I scroll back up the page, the larger logo reappears, but the problem, the small logo is still visibile. How come? What am I doing wrong?

Please note, I have already tried to toggle the event in the 2nd function.

```
<script>
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var value = $(this).scrollTop();
    if ( value < 100 )
        $("#logo").css("display", "none");    
        $("#smalllogo").css("display", "inline");      
    });


    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $("#logo").toggle($(this).scrollTop() < 100);
});
</script>
```

**The HTML**

```
            <a class="" href="index.html">

                <?php if ($logo) { ?>
                    <div id="logo" style="padding-bottom: 30px;">
                        <a href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><img src="logo.png"></a></div>
                <?php } ?>

                <div id="smalllogo">
                    <a href="index.php"><img src="image/smalllogo.png"></a>
                </div>

            </a>
```

**The relevant CSS**

```
#smalllogo{
    display: none;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you'd just toggle it the other way ?

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $("#logo").toggle($(this).scrollTop() < 100);
    $("#smalllogo").toggle($(this).scrollTop() > 100);
});
```